# java draw polyline from an arraylist of points

Tags: java, arraylist, draw, point, polyline

Is it possible to draw a polyline by passing the method an array list of Point values? something like this:

```
 ArrayList<Point> projectilePoints=new ArrayList<Point>();
    Projectile p = new Projectile(11, 17, 73, 37);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        Point point = p.getPositionAt(i);
        projectilePoints.add(point);
    }
    g.drawPolyline(projectilePoints, projectilePoints, 11);
```

What is the correct way to pass in the parameters of x and y points for the polyline?

Comment: Learn to read the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolyline%28int[],%20int[],%20int%29).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). 2) You might (I don't fully understand the question) be able to use a `GeneralPath` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such method takes `Arraylist` of `Point` reference parameter. The Syntax is,

`Graphics.drawPolyline(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)`

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDpc on `Graphics#drawPolyLine` states that you need to pass 2 int arrays that represent the x and y coordinates.

Alternatively, you might use `Graphics2d#draw(Shape)` and pass a `Path2D` shape, that can be prefilled using your points (e.g. by calling `lineTo(x,y)` for all points but the first - for which you might call `moveTo(x,y)`).

Answer (score 1):

Call method `Graphics2D.drawPolyline`.  This method takes an int array of X coordinate values, an int array of Y coordinate values and the number of points.

There is no line drawing method that takes `Point` objects, you have to create int arrays of coordinates.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html